# Changes in custom.css don't apply

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress (theme: future) with a plugin called "Private Blog". They give the possibility to use a custom css (by creating the file custom.css and put it in the theme root).

This is done and has worked so far, but suddenly the changes I do don't apply. When I check Chrome DevTools the file is still used with the old content even though I can see that the new content is saved when I open the file on the server.

How can this be and what can I do about it?

Comment: are you sure that you did it right? the selectors?

Comment: @SCV: Yes, because my previous changes is what is used and when I open custom.css in DevTools I can see the file before my last changes.

Comment: Use the Dev tools to inspect the element.  You can see what classes are being applied.  Maybe it's a specificty problem

Comment: you probably have a typo somewhere in the css ( like open brackets, no space, no semicolon etc..)

Comment: It could just be a browser caching problem - see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19526743/1714) for a way to ensure changes are always downloaded