# Arrow not appears need help of CSS code

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css, flexslider

I am new here, i need little help from you guys. I tried all the way to sort out this problem but found no way, hope someone can help me out.

here is my website http://www.newwebdemo.com/susan/

if you scroll down to section "What People Are Saying" where testimonials appears.

You will notice that left arrow is not appears but right one appears fine, even left side arrow box have arrow as well, but still not appears, can someone help me find where the issue is coming and why it is not appear.

Here is code section of that

```
<ul class="flex-direction-nav">
   <li>
      <a class="flex-prev" href="#"></a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a class="flex-next" href="#"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and here is css of it

```
.flex-direction-nav a {

  width: 42px;

  height: 42px;

  font-size: 24px;

  line-height: 42px;

  margin-top: -21px;

  border-radius: 5px;

  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;

  background: #fff;

  color: #b1b1b1;

  text-shadow: none !important;

  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)" !important;

  opacity: 0 !important;

}

.flex-direction-nav a:hover {

  background: #000;

  color: #fff;

  border-color: transparent;

}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev {

  left: 0 !important;

}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next {

  right: 0 !important;

  left: auto !important;

}



.flex-direction-nav a:before {

  position: relative;

  font-size: 30px;

  font-family: fontello;

  margin-top: -1px;

}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev:before {

  margin-left: 14px;

  content: "î";

  z-index:999999;

}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {

  margin-right: 14px;

  content: "îž";

}



.mini .flex-direction-nav a {

  border: none;

  color: #fff;

  background: #ccc;

  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.mini .flex-direction-nav a:before {

  top: 1px;

}

.mini .flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev {

  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;

}

.mini .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next {

  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;

}

.mini .flex-direction-nav a:hover {

  background: #000;

  color: #fff;

  border-color: transparent;

}



.flex-control-nav {

  width: 100%;

  left: 0;

  bottom: auto;

}

.flex-control-nav li {

  margin: 0 2px;

  display: inline-block;

}

.flex-control-nav li a {

  width: 7px;

  height: 7px;

  display: block;

  background-color: #b9b9b9;

  cursor: pointer;

  text-indent: -9999px;

  border-radius: 4px;

  box-shadow: none !important;

  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)" !important;

  opacity: 0 !important;

}

.flex-control-nav li a.flex-active {

  background-color: #e54939;

}

.nav-bullets-top .flex-control-nav {

  top: -40px;

}

.nav-bullets-bottom .flex-control-nav {

  bottom: -70px;

}

.flex-direction-nav a {

  width: 42px;

  height: 42px;

  font-size: 24px;

  line-height: 42px;

  margin-top: -21px;

  border-radius: 5px;

  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;

  background: #fff;

  color: #b1b1b1;

  text-shadow: none !important;

  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)" !important;

  opacity: 0 !important;

}

.flex-direction-nav a:hover {

  background: #000;

  color: #fff;

  border-color: transparent;

}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev {

  left: 0 !important;

}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next {

  right: 0 !important;

  left: auto !important;

}



.flex-direction-nav a:before {

  position: relative;

  font-size: 30px;

  font-family: fontello;

  margin-top: -1px;

}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev:before {

  margin-left: 14px;

  content: "î";

  z-index:999999;

}

.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {

  margin-right: 14px;

  content: "îž";

}



.mini .flex-direction-nav a {

  border: none;

  color: #fff;

  background: #ccc;

  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.mini .flex-direction-nav a:before {

  top: 1px;

}

.mini .flex-direction-nav a.flex-prev {

  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;

}

.mini .flex-direction-nav a.flex-next {

  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;

}

.mini .flex-direction-nav a:hover {

  background: #000;

  color: #fff;

  border-color: transparent;

}



.flex-control-nav {

  width: 100%;

  left: 0;

  bottom: auto;

}

.flex-control-nav li {

  margin: 0 2px;

  display: inline-block;

}

.flex-control-nav li a {

  width: 7px;

  height: 7px;

  display: block;

  background-color: #b9b9b9;

  cursor: pointer;

  text-indent: -9999px;

  border-radius: 4px;

  box-shadow: none !important;

  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)" !important;

  opacity: 0 !important;

}

.flex-control-nav li a.flex-active {

  background-color: #e54939;

}

.nav-bullets-top .flex-control-nav {

  top: -40px;

}

.nav-bullets-bottom .flex-control-nav {

  bottom: -70px;

}
```

flex-prev not showing arrow, however flex-next class is showing fine the arrow

both contain css classes working, not sure what else is causing here....

Comment: Start off by showing the relevant portion of code here. If it helps, create a minimal reproducible example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: just added code section

Comment: That's not enough information to diagnose the problem. If you can duplicate the problem using jsfiddle, you'll almost certainly get an answer in no time.

Comment: i dont know jsfiddle i tried adding html and css i have, just confused there, can you please just take a look a little and help me on live site please!

Comment: ok i tried jsfiddle, added complete portion of html as well complete css and make run, both arrows appears fine there, how ever not appearing in the website which mean something stopping only left arrow to appear on site, now can you help please

Comment: looks like its working

Comment: As @Mark says, it seems fine.  Maybe the stylesheet is being cached on your computer. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526520/why-do-changes-to-some-php-files-take-so-long-to-show-on-the-live-site/19526743#19526743) has an approach that may help

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing go to the demo of flexslider.right click then click on view page source.after that go into the source of the demo and locate flexslider.css.just copy the css code into your flexslider.css code.then google look for bg_direction_nav.png flexslider.

You'll find two arrow image.download it into your system.then go to flexslider.css and change on line 51:

```css
.flex-direction-nav a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px; 
    margin: -20px 0 0;
    display: block;
    background: url(images/bg_direction_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    position: absolute; top: 50%; cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

Change background:url(point to the newly saved image)

Then save everything.refresh page and u'll get the arrows.

If you post useful please log on to www.facebook.com/brightinfoway and like that page. It is a request. Thanks