# Internet Explorer 9 304 errors

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-9, mime-types, http-status-code-304

Hi my main stylesheet app.css is not loading within IE9.

Below is a screenshot of all the 304 errors it is getting. I have added the text/css MIME types and tried a while host of shims, doctypes and meta tags to fix this with no luck!

It's a wordpress site running off of Foundation 5 (which I have not had issues with in the past)

If anyone knows of anything I can try that would be amazing!

[image]

Comment: 304 is not an error. It indicates that the resource has not been modified since the last time it was downloaded, and the browser/client can use the existing file instead of downloading it again http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#304

Comment: If I am developing a website wouldn't the CSS file be continually modified? As I am changing css and refreshing to see my changes?

Comment: You could try using the file modification time as the version number (so when it changes the URL updates, and the browser fetches it again) - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19526520/why-do-changes-to-some-php-files-take-so-long-to-show-on-the-live-site)