# wordpress style.css load but not use

Tags: css, wordpress, ssl

I'm wordking on a child theme for the website impakt and yesterday we change some ssl certificats.
After this, my page still load my style.css from my child theme BUT he doesn't use it so, my pages build with this css are not working (I can access to them but it's a mess).

If you go to the page
http://impakt.lu/cloche-v2/
you can see he's loading the theme/impakt/style.css but in my page he does not use it (my elements are not using it).

Any solution ? thx

Comment: Maybe it is loading over http instead of https, and the browser is blocking it. Change the Wordpress url to match https if you didnt' already.

Comment: Looking into your sources I can clearly tell that both - the style is being loaded and it is being applied. You can inspect the body styles and will notice ( e.g. height: auto; ) is aplied from your styles.

Comment: Can you give an specific example of which style is not applied correctly? Then we could identify it more easily. Is it a text positioning?

Comment: Any chance your stylesheet's been cached on your computer, so it's just a (local) version problem?  If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19526743/1714) may help

Comment: In this page, you can see the container ".texture". In my css there is a ".texture {
            background-image: url(http://impakt.lu/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cloche-dor-fond.jpg);
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }"
and you can see: it's not applied to the container :/

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens when you try to load secure resources (https) via http or vise-versa. You can follow the instructions [here](https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/web-publishing/https-for-wordpress/) to properly migrate to https.

Comment: I tried yesterday to change the "http" adress with "https" and.. not working

Comment: can you try [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-https/) plugin. perhaps it might help.

Comment: I don't think it's a solution :/
I found out the nav is using the style but the template pages in the child theme are not using it. but for the pages from the main theme, it's working